# jQuery regex alphanumerics prevent symbol and space

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question,
I have jquery function `alphanumers`

```
var alphanumers = /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/;
```

it will not allowed all symbols.

But now I want the `space` including to be not allowed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also disallow space, change it to:

```
var alphanumers = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/;
```

This will allow any character A to Z in either upper- or lower-case, numbers 0 to 9 and the dash character.